# File disappeared during cut process from usb to desktop

Tags: usb

Hello Ubuntu community I am so worried about some important files that i lost during cut process.

I was accessing my USB from GUI and I wanted to cut(move) a folder from USB to the desktop. In that moment my system was slowing down a little bit and the process failed. The problem is that the folder which is already in the desktop is empty and in the USB I have nothing from that folder neither the folder itself. But i think that maybe the files are still there because before making the cut action of the folder my USB had 205 MB free memory and after that still has the same free space. So, is there any possibility to recover the files.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you used the cut action and not yet copy&pasted something else it might even be in clipboard still so pasting it again maybe to test, if not photorec/testdisk is you tool of choice. DO NOT write anything to that stick! Every write action to the stick will make your chances of file recovery smaller.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?